# Column generation

Tags: reference-request, optimization

I'm new to optimization and I was said to study about Column generation and implement it for an optimization  problem. But I cannot find any useful books that has manually solved an example using column generation. It would be more helpful if someone gives me useful link. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Adding additional information especially about the optimization problem itself would improve your post.

Comment: This is not a simple topic. Try Google. Also try: https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~ms79/publications/or46b.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good introduction to column generation in integer programming with an explicit example based on the cutting stock problem in chapter 14 of Vasek Chvatal's book, *Linear Programming*.

In order to understand this, you're going to have to first be familiar with linear programming and the simplex method.  You'll also need some general background in combinatorial optimization.  Another book that you might find helpful is *Combinatorial Optimization* by Papadimitriou and Steiglitz.